# Is 6-ethenyl-4-(prop-2'-enyl) octa-6-en-3-ol a valid name?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, alcohols

I recently study organic chemistry and I read a book by Sana Jamshaid. I came across this compound and I cannot understand why it named **6-ethenyl-4-(prop-2'-enyl) octa-6-en-3-ol**:

> [image: 6-ethenyl-4-(prop-2'-enyl) octa-6-en-3-ol]

I understand that the longest chain is 8, hence octa (but if we go up on the 4th longest can be 9) but I don't understand the **4-(prop-2’-enyl)**. Are there any explanations to why the compound named in such way? The double bond also sits on the 7th and not the 6th.

Comment: The name looks wrong. The longest chain is 10 the second longest nine.

Comment: I cannot rationalize that name either, and the drawing looks off (angles at tertiary carbon are nonsensical). Probably it would help to [draw the same molecule differently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVPd0.png) and proceed from there. It also wouldn't hurt if there were a complete reference to the book. "*The country should know its heroes*", as they say in Russia.

Answer (score 1):

The suggested name
“6-ethenyl-4-(prop-2'-enyl) octa-6-en-3-ol”
is not correct; the closest valid name is
**6-ethenyl-4-(prop-2-en-1-yl)oct-6-en-3-ol.**

However, this name does not describe the compound that is shown in the picture. Note that the parent chain actually is **non-7-en-3-ol** instead of oct-6-en-3-ol, and the longest side chain actually is **but-3-en-1-yl** instead of prop-2-en-1-yl.

Therefore, the correct name for the compound that is shown in the picture is
**(7*E*)-4-(but-3-en-1-yl)-6-ethenylnon-7-en-3-ol.**

Answer (score -1):

I also agree with @Loong, the suggested name "6-ethenyl-4-(prop-2'-enyl) octa-6-en-3-ol" seems incorrect. The correct name for this compound should be (7E)-4-(but-3-en-1-yl)-6-ethenylnon-7-en-3-ol, as @Loong mentioned.

In this compound, the longest carbon chain has 10 carbon atoms, but we select the carbon chain with 9 carbon atoms as it has a functional group (-OH) attached. So, parent chain will be non- as there are 9 carbons.

[image]

Now, we number the chain from left to right, as the main functional group is always assigned the least possible locant.

[image]

So, we see that we get -OH at locant 3, -CH2CH2CH=CH2 at locant 4, -CH=CH2 at locant 6 and double bond at locant 7. So these substituent/functional groups can be named accordingly:

- 3-ol
- (but-3-en-1-yl) (as carbon atom attached to parent chain (alkyl) is always numbered 1)
- ethenyl (vinyl group)
- 7-ene (NOTE: the ending -e will be dropped while writing the complete IUPAC name)

Also, since it is a trans- (w.r.t double bond at locant 7), we put (7E)- in the beginning of the name. (Z is put for cis- )

So, now, the **IUPAC name should be (7E)-4-(but-3-en-1-yl)-6-ethenylnon-7-en-3-ol**

Here are a few resources:

[NCERT Class XI Organic Chemistry - some basic principles and techniques](https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/kech205.pdf)

[Systematic IUPAC nomenclature - Aditya Vardhan V](https://www.adichemistry.com/organic/basics/iupac1/organic-iupac-nomenclature.html#:%7E:text=But%20the%20chain%20with%20the,contains%20multiple%20bonds%20or%20not.)

[cis- and trans- nomenclature in organic compounds](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2016/11/03/alkene-nomenclature-cis-and-trans-and-e-and-z/)